# Interpolate smaller histogram bins (Pandas / Plotly)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a histogram of probability data, where the probabilities are bucketed in bins of size 10. When I display the histogram as a heatmap in plotly using buckets that are the same size as the data, I get this:

[image: bucket size 10]

I'd like to view the heatmap at a finer granularity, like buckets of size 1. Since the data is in buckets of size 10, it looks like this:

[image: bucket size 1]

How do I interpolate the data to fill in values for the gaps?

One idea is to divide the bucket from 190 to 200 evenly between 190-191, 191-192, etc, but that would not accurately represent the bell-curve shape of the histogram. Since the peak is at ~200, ideally there would be more weight at 199-200 than at 190-191.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [distplot](https://plotly.com/python/distplot/). I can probably use that to get a good idea of the fine-grained distribution. I'll post back with the results when I have them.

Comment: It turns out [create_distplot](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_distplot.html#plotly-figure-factory-create-distplot)'s data is just a list of values, whereas I would like to plot a list of x _and_ y values. And sadly, I can't find a curve setting for a regular [histogram](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html).